# How to restrict magento extension use based on domain?

Tags: magento

I am working on magento extension which i need to restrict to specific domains. Means if customer buys the extension for single domain then he can not use the same code for another domain which is not registered with us.

Comment: Take a look @ http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/license-for-local-project/

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I think you should opt for an observer at `controller_action_predispatch` to constantly monitor the current base URL and then disable the module when it's not using the correct base URL.

http://gabrielsomoza.com/magento/disabling-a-module-and-its-output-programmatically/

However, you also need a mechanism to have, say a unique distribution ID, then compare it to a remote service, and do the above. There are tons of ways to do that, I'd prefer a RESTful interface or an XML-RPC service to do that.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is not achievable.

There are a few ways you can implement something like DRM, but everything sucks. You could have a call to your server to check the serialnumber all the time. And to be sure, the buyer doesn't remove your check, you have to encrypt your code.

All this sucks and makes the processing slower. Sell your extension but don't bother your customers like the music industry does.